Question about a set in a normed linear space
Let's say X is a normed, linear vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ that is complete with respect to the metric given by the norm. Let F be a subset of X that is closed and bounded. Question: is the set $\mathbb{C} \cdot F = \{\lambda f: \lambda \in \mathbb{C}, f \in F\}$ closed in X?

No, this set is not always closed. Let $X$ be the complete vector space $\mathbb{C}^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$ with the Euclidean norm. Set $f_n = \left(\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and let $F = \{f_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{(0, 0)\}$. Then $F$ is closed and bounded in $X$. However, setting $\lambda_n = n$, we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda_nf_n = (1, 0)$, which is not an element of $\mathbb{C}\cdot F$, and therefore $\mathbb{C} \cdot F$ cannot be closed.

+1. Nice example!

Second that. Thanks dude!
